# Make button show when another is clicked

Tags: android, button

Tried different solutions but app keeps crashing - at the moment I have 4 image buttons, when the 3 incorrect ones are clicked a cross appears on top of them, and when the correct one is clicked a tick appears on it and sound plays.

That's all working fine, but what I'm struggling with is showing a button (which has an arrow on it) when the correct button is pressed for the user to proceed to the next question.

As with my other buttons/ticks/crosses etc I have declared the arrow in onCreate method....

```
  nextArrow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextArrow);
```

then in my onClickListener method....

```
  case R.id.happybutton:
            tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            nextArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            correct.start();
```

Logcat:

---

```
 07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Autism_App/com.example.Autism_App.Expressions}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at com.example.Autism_App.Expressions.onCreate(Expressions.java:36)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
07-27 17:46:28.493: E/AndroidRuntime(17030):    ... 11 more
```

---

When either or both of the nextArrow lines are in my code it crashes, but when I comment them out it's working fine elsewhere...any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error yo get?

Comment: Are you sure you are declaring R.id.nextArrow in the same layout as the other Buttons?

Comment: logcat added - it says about ImageButton not being cast to Button...I changed it to Button in the xml file as that's what the other buttons were...it's still crashing!

Comment: @coderoligist If you change all ImageButtons to Button the new stacktrace should be posted. Post the xml layouts and the new stacktrace

Comment: Updated - Still saying ImageButton...Button even though they are now all cast to button...I don't understand that at all

Comment: @coderoligist still you haven't posted the relevant xml layout and the java code. Clean and build your project once. Also indicate what is on line 36 `Expressions.java`. The stacktrace indicates a problem at line 36

Comment: Sorry - clean and rebuild worked....thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Probably `R.id.nextArrow` is not inflated. Check if `nextArrow` is `null` and make sure you're inflating the layout that includes the next button.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
>   cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Indicates you have a ImageButton and you are casting it to Button as

```
 nextArrow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextArrow);
```

SHould be

```
 ImageButton nextArrow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextArrow);
```

Comment: I noticed that and fixed it...xml file is now declaring it as a button....and therefore now my original java file (which declares it as a button) should be correct but still crashing!

Comment: @coderoligist as i said the crash may be because of a different reason. If you change the code post the same here. The xml layout the java code and the stacktrace (new one).